# How to check whether a string input from the user contains a number or not?

Tags: c++

The title says it all. I'm looking to check if a string contains even a single digit somewhere. No idea how to do this. If there is a pre-built function for this, I'd still like an unorthodox, long way of actually doing it (if you know what I mean).

Thanks!

Comment: Should be pretty straightforward to convert this to a loop `std::any_of(str.begin(), std.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::is_digit(c);})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there is a pre-built function for this, I'd still like an unorthodox, long way of actually doing it (if you know what I mean).

You could just use a simple for-loop and check if any of the characters present in the string are digits and return `true` if any is found, otherwise `false`:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
// ...

bool contains_number(std::string const& s) {
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        if (std::isdigit(s[i]))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or if you're fine with using [`std::string::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

```cpp
bool contains_number(std::string const& s) {
    return s.find_first_of("0123456789") != std::string::npos;
}
```

Comment: Now then if I wanted to something even more orthodox could I do:  if ( s[i] >= 0 ) ? Would this work as a condition instead of using the isdigit() function?

Comment: @Themeiscool It would be something along those lines, but the digits have to be surrounded with single quotes since you want to compare characters. Moreover, you also need to check if the character's ASCII value is less than or equal to that of `'9'`s: `if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')`

Comment: @Ruks -- concerning your comment, you're right about those tests, but that does not depend on ASCII; it's true for **every** valid character encoding.

Comment: @Ruks Aye thanks a heck lot. I'm really interested in seeing how to formulate this logic instead of using it pre-fabricated (if you know what I mean). You really helped me get it thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

using std::isdigit in iostream
It will return true or false

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isnumber(string n){
    for (int i = 0;i < n.size();i++){
        if (isdigit(n[i]) == 1){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
int main(){
   string n;
   cin >> n;
   if (isnumber(n)){
       cout << "Have number in string";
   }else{
       cout << "Doesn't have number in string";
   }
   return 0 ;
}
```